# Python Seaborn do not show all data

Tags: python, machine-learning, seaborn

I would like to do the testing with seaborn to show some toy data. The python codes as belows:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

def test_seaborn():
    X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, 
                               n_features=20, 
                               n_informative=2,
                               n_redundant=2, 
                               n_classes=2, 
                               random_state=0)

    df = DataFrame(np.hstack((X, y[:, None])),
                   columns = range(20) + ["class"])

    sns.pairplot(df[:50], 
                 vars=[8, 11, 12, 14, 19], 
                 hue="class", 
                 size=1.5)

    sns.plt.show()

if __name__=='__main__':
    test_seaborn()
```

In some guide the plot should be as:(Almost 50 points show in each modules)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH2rZ.jpg)
Actually, I got this plot likes this(a few points):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgFoE.png)

BTW，Environment Information:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
numpy: 1.10.4
scikit-learn:0.17
seaborn: 0.7.0

Can you help me for that? Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the bad plot one. I use same `scikit-learn:0.17` and  `seaborn: 0.7.0` on Ubuntu 14.04. So we might have to wait if someone have the same problem.

Comment: @titipat You means your env run these codes can shows almosts 50 points in each moduels?

Comment: I see the same as @titipat. I ran the exact same code and got the good plot instead of the bad one.

Comment: @Stephen yes, for me, these codes produce the good plot.

Comment: @titipat can you show me the version about numpy and pandas? Thanks.

Comment: @jonnat can you show me the version about numpy and pandas? Thanks.

Comment: @Stephen numpy 1.10.4, pandas 0.17.1, sklearn 0.17, seaborn 0.7. Running on a Mac.

Comment: @Stephen, I use `numpy 1.10.2`, `pandas 0.17.1`, `scikit-learn:0.17`, `seaborn: 0.7.0`. All installed using Anaconda and using `pip 8.0.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have encountered a bug in matplotlib 1.3. The solution is to upgrade your matplotlib. If you prefer not to do that, you'll have to manually set the axes limits for each row and column.

Comment: @mwaskom That is work. Thanks!  My old matplotlib version is 1.3.1,after i upgrade to 1.5.1 then this issue is fixed.